# How does reference to pointer exactly work in C++, and when do we need them (in the case of linked list)

Tags: c++, pointers, pass-by-reference, singly-linked-list

I know that pointers hold the address of a variable. And references point to the same address in the symbol table (that is, the same address of the variable, that they are assigned to).

My question is, how do reference to pointers exactly work. And when do we need them, as opposed to using pointer alone (and not using reference to pointer). It will be helpful if you could explain me the use of reference to pointer, with respect to a singly linked list.

I have the following code that deletes the head pointer of a linked list using a function:

```
struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node* next;
};

struct Node* newNode(int data)
{
    Node* temp = new Node;
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = nullptr;
    return temp;
}

Node* deleteHead(Node* &head)
{
    if (head)
    {
        Node* temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete temp;
    }
    return head;
}

int main()
{
    Node* head = newNode(1);
    head->next = newNode(6);
    head->next->next = newNode(4);
    head->next->next->next = newNode(8);

    head = deleteHead(head);
    Node* temp = head;
    while (temp != nullptr)
    {
        cout << temp->data << " " << endl;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In the `deleteHead(Node* &head)` function, the function takes the argument, `Node* &head`. But, the code works fine,  even when the argument is `Node* head`. for what cases do we need to pass `Node* &` instead of `Node*` in a linked list?

Following is the `deleteHead(Node* &head)` function above, which works the same, if we only use `Node* head` as the argument, instead of `Node* &head`  -

[image: Function that works the same with Node* and Node* &]

Comment: `head = deleteHead(head);` works, but without the reference `deleteHead(head);` would not. At the end of the day a pointer is just another variable (the value just happens to be an address) and if you want to change the value of that variable and make the change stick outside the function you need to pass the variable by reference.

Comment: "How does reference to pointer exactly work in C++" it works exactly the same way as it works for a variable of any other type

Comment: As a side note, what you're doing looks a lot like a C implementation of a linked list. You have the Marvelous Magic of C++™ at your fingertips--make a `List` class and wrap all of the `Node` logic up in there so your list users don't have to worry about any of it!

Comment: Do you really need to get involved in linked lists to see when to use a reference to a pointer?  What about something simple like this? `void foo(int *x) { x = new int;} int main() { int *p=nullptr; foo(p); }` -- Note that `p` is still `nullptr` after `foo` is called.  Why?  How do you fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pass a pointer by reference for the same reason you pass a non-pointer by reference: To let the function modify its value.

Let me use a simpler example

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(int*& x) {
    *x = 42;        // change the value of the int x points to
    x = nullptr;    // change the value of x
}
```

The first line modifies the value `x` points to (but it does not modify `x`). The second line modifies `x` itself.

```
int main() {
    int y = 42;
    int* y_ptr = &y;
    foo(y_ptr);
    if (y_ptr == &y) std::cout << "cannot happen";
}
```

Because we set `x = nullptr`, `y_ptr` will not point to `y` anymore after the call.

Now if we modify `foo` to not take a reference we get:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(int* x) {
    *x = 42;        // change the value of the int x points to
    x = nullptr;    // change the value of x
}
```

Again the first line modifies the `int` pointed to by `x`. However, now the second line only has an effect on `x` local to the function.

```
int main() {
    int y = 42;
    int* y_ptr = &y;
    foo(y_ptr);
    if (y_ptr == nullptr) std::cout << "cannot happen";
}
```

The value of `y_ptr` cannot change by passing it to `foo`, because it is passed by value.

In your code you have

```
Node* deleteHead(Node* &head)
{
    if (head)
    {
        Node* temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete temp;
    }
    return head;
}
```

And when you write `head = deleteNode(head)` two things are happening:

- the function modifies `head` (because it is passed by reference) to point to `head->next`.
- the function also returns this "new" head (pointing to `head->next`) and that is assigned to `head`.

So you basically asign to `head`twice. Because `head` is passed by reference `deleteNode` would do the right thing without using the return value:

```
deleteNode(head);  // this already does modify head
```

...or put the other way around: If you return the "new" head (`head->next`) from the fucntion and assign it to `head`, then it does not matter if you pass the pointer by reference, because the assignment done inside the function has the same effect.

Your code is similar to

```
int* bar(int*& x) {
   x = nullptr;
   return x;
}
```

and then call it via

```
int y = 42;
int* y_ptr = &y;
y_ptr = bar(y_ptr);
```

where the same effect could be achieved by not using the returned value `bar(y_ptr)`. Or the same without pointers (because pointers really make no difference here):

```
int moo(int& x) {
    x = 0;
    return x;
}

int x = 42;
x = moo(x);     // same as `moo(x)`
```

PS: You dont need both (return the pointer and assign it already in the function), so better make the function return `void`.

Comment: can you please point some scenarios where I should use reference to pointers in a function (for example, in a linked list)?

Comment: @VikramSingh your `deleteNode` is the best example. You should make it return nothing (`void`), because that just opens the door to using it wrong (what it the caller forgets to use the returned value?)

Answer (score 1):

So,

both, reference and pointer contain an address of variable/memory.
reference has semantic of variable (if you set the value, you write data into referenced memory),
pointer has semantic of pointer (if you set the value, pointered memory isn't changed) and you can set the pointer which addresses an other memory.

about deleteHead(Node* &head) - you use the reference of real variable that contains pointer of Node. The function returns new value of head in the same variable and as return value too.

Answer (score 1):

References are "safe pointers" that are used with value semantics (which is really helpful in an operator overloading context), so the usage of references is very similar to the usage of pointers in C, except these points:

1. References hold a single value and not an array
2. References are non-null (which is not always desirable)

It means that you can (or, should) pass a reference whenever you want to change the original passed variable (and not a copy of it).

Saying that, the C (rought) equivalent to your function is `Node* deleteHead(Node** head)`.
Note that since you passed a reference, the original `head` variable was modified and thus your function becomes a bit weird, since it both modifies head and returns its value.
You can use one of the following options:

(1) deletes head (if the list size is non-empty) and returns a pointer to the next element, this is not advisable since it will leave head as a dangling pointer. This is your original function but it does not receive a reference.

```cpp
Node* deleteHead(Node* head)
{
    if (head)
    {
        Node* temp = head; // You might want to use auto
        head = head->next;
        delete head;
    }
    return head;
}
```

(2) The same as your function, but returns no value (because you already modified head). This one will not work without passing a reference.

```cpp
void deleteHead(Node* &head)
{
    if (head)
    {
        Node* temp = head->next; 
        delete head; // deletes the content of head
        head = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: **References are "safe pointers"* is questionable. Often no pointers are involved at all. A better way to describe a reference is by calling it an alias to another object. Also note that you can pass arrays by reference.

Comment: References are pointers in any decent compiler (clang, g++ and cl), you can check it yourself in windbg / gdb. It is true that the standard don't state anything about the implementation of references but there is simply no other convenient way of doing so.
And when you say I can pass array as reference you probably mean that T[] modifies the underlying elements, but this is again, since T[] is a C++ alias to T* const.

Answer (score 1):

With the reference to pointer deleteHead function, you may use head = deleteHead(head) or deleteHead(head) since head is just a reference of head in the main function, any change on head in the deleteHead function is actually applied on head variable in the main function. With the pointer version, you must use head = deleteHead(head).